# Structure tensor based off index

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to join multiple tensors based off a corresponding index tensor. As a toy example I have a tensor `A = [[0,1,2],[2,3,4]]` with a corresponding index vector `B = [0,1]` and another tensor `C = [[5,6,7],[8,9,10],[11,12,13]]` with a corresponding index vector `D = [0,1,2]`. I seek to return a tensor such that `E = [[0,1,2],[5,6,7],[2,3,4],[8,9,10],[11,12,13]]` where the values with the same indices are grouped together. I'm trying to efficiently do this as it is contained within my NN model and can suffer from performance issues during the backward propagation.

I was able to do achieve this by constructing a dictionary and for looping as such:

```
E = defaultdict(list)
for vector, indices in zip([A,C],[B,D]):
    for vector, i in enumerate(vector):
        E[indices[i]].append(vector)
E = list(E.values())
```

This approach however slows down model training significantly. Is there a way to do this more efficiently? Pytorch's various index_ operations don't seem to address this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume both `A` and `C` tensors have a different number of rows but same number of columns.

```
A = torch.LongTensor([[0,1,2],[2,3,4]]) # torch.Size([2, 3])
C = torch.LongTensor([[5,6,7],[8,9,10],[11,12,13]]) # torch.Size([3, 3])

assert A.dim() == C.dim() == 2
assert A.size(1) == C.size(1)

shape_E = (A.size(0) + C.size(0), A.size(1))
E = torch.zeros(*shape_E).long()

# Two possible cases
if A.size(0) > C.size(0): # C has fewer rows
    n_rows = C.size(0)
    E[np.arange(0, 2*n_rows, 2), :] = A[:n_rows, :]
    E[np.arange(1, 2*n_rows, 2), :] = C[:n_rows, :]
    E[2*n_rows:, :] = A[n_rows:, :]
else: # A has fewer rows
    n_rows = A.size(0)
    E[np.arange(0, 2*n_rows, 2), :] = A[:n_rows, :]
    E[np.arange(1, 2*n_rows, 2), :] = C[:n_rows, :]
    E[2*n_rows:, :] = C[n_rows:, :]

print(E)
```

Output

```
tensor([[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 5,  6,  7],
        [ 2,  3,  4],
        [ 8,  9, 10],
        [11, 12, 13]])
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to take into account the indexes B and D which are important for this construction. This seems to solve the singular case of this toy example. I need it to read in B and D as there are instances where it matters. For example, B = [0,1,1] D = [0, 0, 1, 2, 2]